# Stack Overflow Blog top bar flair does not use thousands separators

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, top-bar, blog

The flair in the top bar of [the new blog site](https://stackoverflow.blog/) is missing a thousands separator:

[image]

My reputation is showing as 21988 while on the Q&A sites, it's shown as 21,988:

[image]

Comment: On MSE: [Add thousands separator to reputation in stack overflow blog header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392667)